# Parsing value from the Jmeter string response

Tags: regex, parsing, groovy, jmeter

I'm trying to get a value of `post_data[‘postcode’]` on Jmeter. I tried to parse with JSR223 PostProcessor with the below code but looks like my code is not able to find that variable name.

Response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
    parent.$("#dialog-message div").html("");

    var url = '';
    var post_data = {};
    post_data[‘user’] = “value1”;
    post_data[‘city’] = “value2”;
    post_data[‘postcode’] = “value3”;
    post_data[‘country’] = “value3”;

</script>
```

JSR223 PostProcessor groovy script:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
String stringToSearch=prev.getResponseDataAsString();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("post_data[‘postcode’] = (\\w+)");   
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);

if (m.find()){
    vars.put("postcode", m.group(1));
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, because you use `\w+` without matching the quotes and do not escape `[`.  Use `"post_data\\[[‘']postcode[’']]\\s*=\\s*[“'\"]([^\"”']+)[\"”']"`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. Looks like it may work but also throwing an error, do you have any idea about this? ```RROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.log() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [value3]```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to surround your match group with quotation marks
2. You need to escape [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)
3. Groovy provides [match operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_match_operator) out of box so you can simplify your code as:

   ```
   vars.put('postcode', (prev.getResponseDataAsString() =~ /post_data\[‘postcode’\] = “(\w+)”/)[0][1])
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

More information:

- [Groovy Regular Expressions - The Definitive Guide](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-regular-expressions-the-definitive-guide/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)